# Show that the fix points of a function couldn't be in the interior

Tags: proof-verification, fixed-point-theorems

I want to solve the following problem:

Show that the fix points of a function $f:\mathbb B^n\rightarrow \mathbb B^n$ could possibly not be in the interior.
By this, Show that the Brouwer fixed-point theorem isn't true for the open ball $B_1^0 (0)$

Then we consider $n=1$ so we have the function $(x-1)/2$ in $(-1,1)$ and this proves both requirements, am I right? or what function could I use? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You need to state all hypotheses on $f$; if $f$ is the identity, then all points are fixed.

Comment: Well these are all the hypotheses :(

Comment: @TZakrevskiy The goal is to show the fixed points "could possibly not be" in the interior, not that they must be in the interior (i.e. produce a counterexample where the fixed points are not in the interior). OP, your understanding of the problem and solution seem to be correct.

Comment: To both requirements right?

Comment: You satisfied the first requirement when you found a function without any interior fixed points. Regarding the second: you have found a function $f : B_1^0(0) \to B_1^0(0)$  that does not have *any* fixed points. (it does not have any fixed points in the interior of the ball, so it does not have *any* fixed points as a map $B_1^0(0) \to B_1^0(0)$). If the Brouwer fixed point theorem *were* true for $B_1^0(0)$, what would it say? Would this contradict what you have already found?

Comment: To finish the proof, I would say find an example for any $n$ (this will only take a very slight modification to the function you already have).

Comment: The Euclidean norm in n-diemnsions right?

Comment: ? I'm not sure what you mean by that: just use $\dfrac{1}{2}( x - (1,0,0,\dots,0))$

Comment: right :), I was thinking replacing x with |x| :), and let me check your other comment

Comment: Don't do that: you want a map from the ball, *to* the ball. Taking $|x|$ is a map from the ball to the real numbers.

Comment: jajajaja right :), then I just take 1 in n dimensions, this is (1,0,0,0,...,) and for the other thing I can't figure out what do you want that I find in the contradiction :)

Comment: I have it, if the brouwer thm is true for the open ball, there will be a fix point there, but we have found a counterexample :)